# Calculate area of a triangle

Tags: computational-geometry, homework

I have another problem that I can't figure out.

A triangle har 2 of its summits in points (7.788,0,1.95), (0,7.788,1.95), and the last one on the curve with all the points (7.788,7.788,a^2+1.95), a is a real number. Calculate the area f(a) of the triangle as a function of a and calculate where it takes its minimal value.

I tried the following. 
Because I can't calculate vectors from points, I counted by hand:

```
u1 = {-7.788, 7.788, 0}
u2 = {0, 7.888, a^2}
```

Then I did that:

```
(Norm[Cross[u1, u2]])/2
```

The output was:

```
1/2 Sqrt[3773.86 + 60.6529 Abs[a]^4 + Abs[0. + 7.788 a^2]^2]
```

Which is not the right solution.

How should I do this?

Comment: How do you know it is not correct?

Comment: Let's define  `A = {7.788,0,1.95}`, `B= {0,7.788,1.95}` and `F[a_]:={7.788,7.788,a^2+1.95}`. You can `Cross` two edge vectors of the triangle emanating from a common corner like this: `Norm[Cross[B-A,F[a]-A]]/2`. The result is the same as yours. For minimization, you can use the observation that `a` is a minimizer of area if and only if `a` is a minimizer of `Cross[B - A, F[a] - A].Cross[B - A, F[a] - A]` (that's the square of the norm!). I think you can do it on your own from this point on (you know how to minimize a quadratic function, right?)

Comment: @Kuba: because I entered it in the system and it was wrong.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher: no sorry I don't. When we had it in class I used to derivate and search for f'(a)=0

Comment: @Dovendyr In my system it looks ok. I'm joking ofc, the point is, how do you validate it? As long as the area for given a is correct it is fine.

Comment: So, what would be `f`? Maybe this `f[a_] := Cross[B - A, F[a] - A].Cross[B - A, F[a] - A];`? Solving for the zeros of `f'`: `Solve[
 f'[a] == 0, a]`.

Comment: @Kuba: we have one of those programs with holes, where we write the result of our computation. It says I'm wrong, but not WHICH one is wrong :)

Comment: Dear @HenrikSchumacher, thank you for your help. I did tried with your method, (and even f[a_] := Cross[B - A, F[a] - A]^2), the output I get is a=0 . More exactly {{a -> 0}, {a -> 0.}, {a -> 0.}}. But when I enter a=0 in my system it says it's wrong.

And why would you need to square the norm?

Comment: Squaring the norm is a common trick to obtain a differentiable function. For example `x \[Function] Abs[x]` is not differentiable, but `x \[Function] Abs[x]^2` is...

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher we can use `ComplexExpand` earlier which will help too

Comment: I'm sorry, when exactly do i need to use ComplexExpand? And why 0 is not a solution?

Comment: You should take your expression and simplify with `Simplify[exp, Assumptions -> Element[a, Reals]]`. That will get rid of the `Abs` and then you can differentiate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use Area:

```
Area[
 Triangle[{{7.788, 0, 1.95}, {0, 7.788, 1.95}, {7.788, 7.788, 
    a^2 + 1.95}}]]
```

> 1/2 Sqrt[3678.78 + 121.306 a^4]

```
Minimize[%, a]
```

> {30.3265, {a -> -1.49931*10^-16}}

Comment: Nice! I have test on monday, hope I will remember that :)

Comment: Be aware, if you are supposed to be learning vector calculations, this might not be an acceptable test answer!

Answer (score 1):

Just summing up the code:

```
A = {7.788, 0, 1.95};
B = {0, 7.788, 1.95};
F[a_] := {7.788, 7.788, a^2 + 1.95}

h[a_] := Cross[B - A, F[a] - A].Cross[B - A, F[a] - A]; 
f[a_]:= Sqrt[h[a]]/2;
Solve[h'[a] == 0, a]
```

> {{a -> 0}, {a -> 0.}, {a -> 0.}}

So, $a = 0$ is the minimizer. This illustrates that:

```
Manipulate[
 Graphics3D[{
   Point[{A, B, F[a]}],
   Text[f[a], F[a] + {1, 1, 1}],
   Triangle[{A, B, F[a]}]
   },
  PlotRange -> {-20, 20}],
 {{a, 0}, -10, 10}
 ]
```

For the answer of your exercise: The exercise asks for minimal *value* of the function `f`. So that's

```
f[0]
```

> 30.3265

Comment: Thank you so much for your help today! It does ask me the area for f(a) and the minimum for a=-.... ?

Comment: You're welcome. Well, I guess, it isn't a good idea to replace teachers by computers, is it? $a=0$ or $a = 0.$ _should_ be accepted as answer, then. As far as I can tell, you did nothing wrong. It is a pity that young people's enthusiam for mathematics gets broken by such unmathematical obstacles. Take as today's lesson that everybody makes mistakes sometimes, be it students, teachers, or computer programmers. And simply move on.

Comment: I redid the problem and it seems it was me who was wrong. I had a slightly different solution than yours, you had 3678.78, I had 3773.86. I guess one really needs to do the vectors properly and not calculate by hand. I wish you a great day!

Comment: Thanks! Have a great day, too!